# Another way to say "For Sale"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm creating a billboard for a real estate client and was looking for an alternative way to say for "For Sale"

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: "Available for purchase"

Comment: Willing to negotiate an ownership transferal. ;-)

Comment: It might help to tell us why the universally accepted “for sale” is no good here.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your feedback.  "For Sale"  is acceptable- I was just looking for something different then what is typical, with the same meaning

Answer (score 3):

Consider,

***now selling***

> [Google Image](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22now+selling%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=imnv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHuN2o3JrMAhWIOxoKHbd_D20Q_AUIBigB&dpr=2)

***up for sale***

> *Fig.* available for purchase. (Typically: *be ~*; *come ~*; *put something ~*.)
>
> *When this lot comes up for sale, let me know*. *Is this property up for sale?*
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+for+sale)

[***on the market***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22real+estate%22+%22houses+on+the+market%22&biw=396&bih=260&noj=1&prmd=sinv&ei=PwwWV52EFouWsgHSmqyACw&start=10&sa=N&dpr=2)

> For sale; *also*, available for buying. This phrase, first put as *in the market*, dates from the late 1600s; the first recorded use of the phrase with *on* was in 1891.
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+market)
>
> *Is this property on the market?*
>
> [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22to+be+offered%22+%22for+sale%22+%22available%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9guu_uZrMAhXFOBoKHdzmCaMQ_AUIBygA&biw=483&bih=317&dpr=2#q=%22is+this+property+on+the+market%22)

Comment: Why use 3 words when 2 will do: especially on a billboard?  I would say that "up for sale" & "on the market" are more commonly used in speech & in a sentence, than on a billboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen "on offer" used to mean "for sale"

Comment: "On offer" does **not** mean "For sale" (at least in the UK): it means someone has made an offer to buy the property, and if you're interested you need to act quickly and come up with a higher offer.

Comment: ... or possibly that the prospective buyer has still got to find a buyer for their own property, and they cannot proceed with the offer until that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

> Available now

I've easily found a few instances of this used with references to property:

- [Usage 1](https://www.appearhere.co.uk/spaces/available-now)
- [Usage 2](http://www.regenda.org.uk/homes-available-now)
- [Usage 3](http://studenthomes.london.ac.uk/rooms-available-now)

Comment: -1 All three of your links are to properties that are available for *rent / letting* - **not** properties that are for **sale**.  When I read your suggestion of "Available now", I immediately thought that it was usually used for lettings - not for sales - which is why I checked the links.

Comment: @TrevorD I didn't consider that but yeah, you're right. There's no logical reason why there should necessarily be that implication but I do agree it exists.

Comment: I don't know, but I'd hazard a guess that it's because house buying in the UK is rarely a quick - or "*now*" - process.  Unless you're a cash buyer, *and* the property being bought is empty or the seller can move out quickly, it usually takes several weeks or even months (if there's a long chain) to complete the process.  And the legal processes can also take time to complete.  Hence a property for sale is rarely "Available *now*".